# style any element after one specific element

Tags: css

Given a set of paragraphs in a random order

```
<article>
  <p class='red'> red </p>
  <p class='green'> green </p>
  <p class='blue'> blue </p>
  <p class='purple'> purple </p>
</article>
```

Two rules :

- All paragraphs placed after the red will have a `backround-color` red.
- All paragraphs after the blue will have the `color` blue

How to do it with CSS ?

*Note that the order is random, and inserting some custom class in the html is not possible.*

**The example below is here to SHOW the visual of the result, its code is *not* correct**.

```html
<article>
  <p class='red'> red </p>
  <p class='green' style='background-color:red;'> green </p>
  <p class='blue' style='background-color:red;'> blue </p>
  <p class='purple' style='background-color:red; color:blue;'> purple </p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` to target all *next adjacent siblings*:

```css
.red ~ p {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue ~ p {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p class='red'> red </p>
  <p class='green'> green </p>
  <p class='blue'> blue </p>
  <p class='purple'> purple </p>
</article>
```

Comment: probably instead of equal we should use contains so it works if we have many classes

Comment: by the way I don't see why you used attribute selector ... we can go with classes

Comment: Yes OFC I first thought it has something to do with targeting elements by attr `style` than I overthought my answer. Thx

Comment: Brilliant. I never knew exactly what were '~' and '+' as CSS selectors